# Automatically update comment votes

Tags: feature-request, comment-voting

Question and answer vote counts update automatically now, which is nice.

Could the comment votes do the same? It's a confusing inconsistency at the moment that I have to <kbd>F5</kbd> for one and not the others.

Comment: They update when you load more comments..

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Okay, that's fine, when (a) there are more comments, and (b) I want to load them, and (c) I haven't already loaded them.

Comment: Hence my remark being a comment. I am otherwise 'meh, -0' on your feature request.